# How to read Layer in AutoLisp

Tags: autocad, autolisp

How to read layer from poline?

e.g with this i can get (8. "LAYER_NAME") but i wanna see onyl LAYER_NAME because I want to later check by name something

```
(defun c:test ( / ent enx )
    (if (setq ent (car (entsel)))
        (progn
            (setq enx (entget ent))
            (assoc 8 enx)
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line

```
(assoc 8 enx)
```

to

```
(cdr (assoc 8 enx))
```

Comment: oh so this is a list...
How convert it to string ?

Comment: cdr returns everything but the first element of the list. In case where `(assoc 8 enx)` is two-element list, `(cdr (assoc 8 enx))` returns string. Which we can confirm by `(type(cdr(assoc 8 enx)))`. In other case where we use multi element list the second element we can select by `(cadr )`. Convert any type to string we can done by function `(vl-princ-to-string)`.